# How do I get the new Codename One GUI builder? I cannot find a download link anywhere

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I have been learning Codename One from the IntelliJ IDE. I have the plugin for CN1 version 6.0.2. It uses the OLD GUI designer. I have been reading about their NEW GUI Builder and want to try it out, but I cannot for the life of me find anywhere to get the thing. Does anyone out there know how to install this "Invisible" GUI Builder?

Answer (score 0):

It's builtin to the IDE. You can right click one of your packages and select to create a GUI builder form. Then select it in the right click and select `Codename One` -> `GUI Builder`.

See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-gui-builder-autolayout-signin-form-responsive.html

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I finally figured that out. It is part of the plugin, but you have to launch it and use it in a different way. This was not very obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind folks. Shai Almog answered my question. I actually figured it out eventually as the answer was right in front of my face.